# Find letters in columns which are same like in first column and print it

Tags: awk, split, match

I have table with values and I have to find match: first column with others and print the match.

INPUT:

```
A:0  A:0.7541   A:0.7396    A:0.7694
A:0  0:0        0:0         0:0
C:0  C:0.8408   C:0.8459    C:0.7939
G:0  G:0.3415   G:0.3290    G:0.4228
G:0  G:0.0343   G:0.0378    T:8.237e06,G:0.02437
C:0 C:0.3895    C:0.3837    A:8.255e06,T:8.255e06,C:0.3623
```

OUTPUT:

```
    A:0  0.7541     0.7396      0.7694
    A:0  0          0           0
    C:0  0.8408     0.8459      0.7939
    G:0  0.3415     0.3290      0.4228
    G:0  0.0343     0.0378      0.02437
    C:0  0.3895     0.3837      0.3623
```

For last row.. if C is in the second column, print only number after matching letter C in this case, same for all columns, but there could be more values separated by ",". So print only the number which contain the match letter C in this case for this row.
 I wrote :

```
awk '{split ($1,a,":");split ($2,b,":"); split($3,c,":"); split($4,d,":");
      if(a[1]=b[1] && a[1]=c[1] && a[1]==d[1]) print $0}' /home/fil/Desktop/uprava.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$  awk '{key=substr($1,1,2);
         n=split($NF,last,",");
         if(n>1) for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if(last[i]~key) {$NF=last[i]; break}
         for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) sub(key,"",$i); 
         print}' file | column -t

A:0  0.7541  0.7396  0.7694
A:0  0:0     0:0     0:0
C:0  0.8408  0.8459  0.7939
G:0  0.3415  0.3290  0.4228
G:0  0.0343  0.0378  0.02437
C:0  0.3895  0.3837  0.3623
```